# Resource Group, Storage Account and Availability Set in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

Recently I started to use Microsoft Azure Free Trial and I have gone through the link

I created a VM with the help of references. Also I read about **Resource Group**, **Storage Account** and **Availability Set** but I couldn’t understand the requirement and differences among all.

Please be kind to explain the requirement and differences among **Resource Group**, **Storage Account** and **Availability Set**.

Comment: Welcome to SO! A simple search about these terms will lead you to ample documentation. For example, first link when I searched for Resource Groups lead me here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups. I would suggest you do that and come back with specific questions that you may have about these.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: To create a VM or before creating a VM on Microsoft Azure, I read some references. Some references create Availability Set and Storage Account before creating a VM and some references ignored creating Availability Set and Storage Account. That’s why I got confused.

Comment: Creating Resource Group is the first step and primary step. Also I noticed that Resource Group with the name of NetworkWatcherRG created automatically. I couldn't understand why?

Comment: @user741975 Sorry for the delayed replay, you could @ me for a quick replay. I would explain what you want to know in my below answer.

Comment: Amy update? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yes, helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, these three resources are the logic resources, solutions for some requirement.

The [Resource Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#resource-groups) is the basic solution for you to manage other resources in the ARM module. As the definition shows:

> A container that holds related resources for an Azure solution. The
>   resource group includes those resources that you want to manage as a
>   group. You decide how to allocate resources to resource groups based
>   on what makes the most sense for your organization

The [Storage Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-introduction), you can also think it as a logic group for storage, a storage solution. It defines some types for different data requirement. And finally, the data still will be stored in the physical disk.

> Azure Storage offers a massively scalable object store for data
>   objects, a file system service for the cloud, a messaging store for
>   reliable messaging, and a NoSQL store.

The [Availability Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/manage-availability), it's a solution for the high availability. Create resources in the 
Availability Set. It will help you avoid some accidents without downtime. Also, it can Prevent some erroneous operations from expanding with the update domain and fault domain. In one word, it provides redundancy to your application.

**update**

As you ask in the comment, first, when you create the VM, the resource group is necessary. But the Availability Set is not necessary, it just created for the high availability. You can create it or not, all dependant on your requirement.

For the storage account, there are two points I think you should pay attention to.

**One** is that the storage account is just for the unmanaged VM, to store the OS disk as a VHD file that you can manage it yourself. If you create a managed VM, the storage account is not needed to you.

**Another** is that the storage account also can store the logs, such as the diagnostic log. If you do not want to store the logs, the storage account is also not needed to you.

Note: If needed, you could just create one storage account to store the unmanaged VM OS disk and the logs as you want.